# Remove symbol and text from url htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to remove some specific text (and all characters after it from a url) - have tried several options, but I can't get any of them to work, a sample url is:

`/yacht-sales/yacht/eclipse1?title=http://www.oceanindependence.com/yacht-sales/yacht/daydream&submit=`

It's everything from the ?title= - that needs to be removed, so the final url would be:

/yacht-sales/yacht/eclipse1

there is another site on the same server that uses ? in it's url's, so removing everything from the ? onwards did cause problems when I tried it, and I did also try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?title=http$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L,NE]
```

But this didn't work, sorry am not really good at things like this, if anyone can help at all?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`%{QUERY_STRING}` doesn't contain first `?` and since its not ending with `http` hence don't put `$` there.

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)title=http.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Rather : RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [R=301,L,NE]

Comment: @jacouh: Actually there is no real need to capture `$1` since `%{REQUEST_URI}` will have same value with a leading slash.